# SSH local machines without .local

Tags: networking, server, ssh

At the office network I'm able to connect to the local raspberry pi doing this :

```
ssh pi@raspberry
```

At home I'm not able to connect to my local raspberry unless I add .local like this :

```
ssh pi@raspberry.local
```

When I ssh without typing .local, it says that the host is unknown. How can I ssh local devices without .local ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. raspberry & raspberry.local are hostnames  (they get converted to ip addresses).  obviously your office knows how to interpret the raspberry hostname, but your home network doesn't as it only knows it as raspberry.local.  change your hostname from raspberry.local to raspberry.  what you use to interpret hostnames I don't know, but offices usually use DNS (domain name service) more than the much older but simpler hostname-list conversion (ie. /etc/hosts) which you may be using at home.

Comment: isn't that a router thing? With my fritzbox I can use either `pi.local` or just `pi`

Comment: Put a line in  `/etc/hosts` like this: `[ip-address]  raspberry`.

Comment: @Jos I did what you say, rebooted but changed nothing, got the same issue (unknown host). Maybe it's my router but I can't modify a lot with it...

Comment: RoVo is right, this is a problem with the name resolution and can be fixed if you can change your home router settings. If you use the same computer at work and at home, I'm afraid that the solution proposed by Jos will not work

Comment: @Lawris You shouldn't need to reboot; and, if the ip address you put in is correct, you should at least be able to `ping raspberry`.

Comment: same to me, with my mac and windows machine I can just "ssh pi" but with my ubuntu I need to "ssh pi.local"